# Python Script to transfer file from AWS S3 to Azure BLOB in databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, amazon-s3, azure-databricks

Trying to copyfile AWS S3 to Azure blob storage using Access Key ID and Access secret Key ID in databricks.

```
Code:
====
 set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='ABCDED'
 set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='12345'

 azcopy cp "https://s3://emp-data/tsc/" "https://empdata.blob.core.windows.net/awstosf/" --recursive
```

The above code is not working and getting invalid syntax

Comment: This is shell code. If you're in databricks, you'll want the [`%sh` magic](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#mix-languages). You'll want `export` rather than `set` if your databricks hosts are linux-based

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Databricks, to work with CLI tools, you need to install `databricks-cli` using `pip install databricks-cli`. Also, configure the cli token using `databricks configure --token` command.

Also, instead of setting the variable programmatically, you should set them using UI in clusters. Follow: **Databticks -> Cluster -> Environment Variables**. So, your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<access-key>` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret-access-key>` will be set in cluster level.

Source: [File manipulation Commands in Azure Databricks](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/storage-options-and-file-manipulation-commands-in-azure-databricks/)

Comment: databricks-cli doesn't work with S3 or Azure storage

Comment: @Alex, but running azcopy command can only be possible through databricks-cli, right?

Comment: No, databricks-cli runs on your machine, and user needs to run AWS-related things inside Databricks

Comment: So is it possible?